# Blackberry wine yeast?

Tags: yeast, wine

I am making a one gallon batch of blackberry wine. What type of yeast would you recommend? I would like the wine to be on the sweet side. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you specifically interested in wine other wise I would go with a champagne yeast. I made a batch of champagne out of sloe berry juice and it turned out great. To sweeten the champagne you can add more juice or other fruit juices when re bottling it. Make sure that you take the first fermentation to at least 10-12% as bottles may explode if you add to much sugar when bottle fermenting. (You will need to make your own calculations on this depending on the yeast).

Here are a few yeasts that could be used for this purpose.

- [WLP715](https://www.whitelabs.com/yeast/wlp715-champagne-yeast)
- [Redstar Pasteur Blanc](http://www.midwestsupplies.com/red-star-pasteur-champagne.html)
- [Lavin EC-1118](http://www.midwestsupplies.com/lalvin-ec-1118-champagne.html)

There are several others but one of these should do.

It may also be a good idea to use smaller bottles. I din't use champagne bottles as those are expensive. I just used smaller bottles about 750ml. Here is a picture of the bottles I used.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**K1V-1116**

S. cerevisiae • cerevisiae

Selected by the ICV in Mont­pellier, France, among numerous killer strains isolated and studied by Pierre Barre at INRA.

When fermented at low temperatures (16°C/61°F) with proper nutrition, it is a strong floral ester producer, especially in neutral or high-yield varieties.
Among the high ester production strains, Lalvin V1116 is the most tolerant of difficult fermentation conditions such as extreme temperatures, high alcohol (18% v/v) and low turbidity.

Ferments well under stressed conditions and is useful in restarting stuck fermentations, especially when relative fructose levels remain high.

**D 47**

S. cerevisiae • cerevisiae
Enoferm ICV D47TM is an isolate from Suze-la-Rousse in the Côtes du Rhône in France. It was selected for the produc­tion of full-bodied, barrel-fermented Chardonnay and other white varietals.

Fermentations are characterized by a short lag phase followed by a regular fermentation. Will tolerate a fer­mentation temperature range of 15-20°C(59-68°F).

It is a high polysaccharide producer and wines made with it are known for their accentuated fruit and great volume.
Excellent results are obtained for barrel-fermented Chardonnay.